# Implement Cepstral analysis in Matlab

Tags: cepstral-analysis

I have a bit complex time signal. When trying to plot its spectrum, I get some weird result. Denoting the time signal as `x` and time vector as `t`, whether I use the definition of the cepstrum by typing this formulae `xcepstrum = real(ifft(log(abs(fft(x)))));` or I use Matlab function `cceps` I get the same result. The problem is that the result doesn't make any sense. Here is a plot of the signal.

[image: Signal in different domains]

The values that appear as 0 in the cepstrum aren't really zero. Whren plotting using the `semilogy` function, I get this plot.
[image]